# ShaderDesigner multi texture not work

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I am using ShaderDesigner version 1.5.9.6 to develop GLSL. So confused why the multi texture just cant work! Does anyone know? thx for answer.

Vertex Shader:

```
void main()
{
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    gl_TexCoord[1] = gl_MultiTexCoord1;
    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
uniform sampler2D BaseImage;
uniform sampler2D BlendImage;

uniform float Opacity;

void main()
{
    vec4 baseColor = texture2D(BaseImage, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
    vec4 blendColor = texture2D(BlendImage, gl_TexCoord[1].st);
    gl_FragColor = blendColor;
}
```

BlendImage cant show in ShaderDesigner, although BaseImage is okay. I definetly sure has set Texture Units 0 and 1 for both sampler.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What GLSL version are you targetting here?

Comment: It appears you are using multiple versions of GLSL in the vertex and fragment shader. There is a lot of undefined behaviour in this area, and might well be the cause of your problems.

Comment: @Bartvbl Actually I just test the tutorial code in ShaderDesigner soft. No any syntax error and compiled link both okay, also use baseColor can show correct ! GLSL version 4.5.0. newer to opengl, appologize.

Comment: @Bartvbl my fault, GLSL version not sure. the ShaderDesigner ide only shows Driver capabilities---Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
Version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 368.81
Renderer: GeForce GTX 750/PCIe/SSE2

Comment: @santi: Different versions of the OpenGL shading language (GLSL) have different ways of writing the shader. You are mixing and matching versions here, so these shaders will probably never work unless you extensively rewrite one of them to be written in the same version of the language as the other.

Comment: @Bartvbl: The above shader code is 100% 1.10. There's nothing there from later versions. There is no "mixing and matching" going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think there is some issue with texture coordinates for the second image.

Nothing wrong with the shaders. Try replacing this line. It worked for me.

```
gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
gl_TexCoord[1] = gl_MultiTexCoord0; // this line replaced...
gl_Position = ftransform();
```

Unfortunately I could not find a way to correct this in the application. When you write your own OpenGL apps, you won't have this issue.

The two texture units 0 and 1 are these.

[image: TextureUnit0]

[image: TextureUnit1]

Here is the output.

[image: Sphere showing rocky texture and four color texture mixed from example]

Comment: Are u sure buddy? I tried this, but got all the same texture. Both are TextureUnit0. Is something wrong with ShaderDesigner?

Comment: Did you change the textures? don't make any other changes except the one line stating `gl_MultiTexCoord0`; don't change texture units or anything else.

Comment: I've added output photos to my answer. @santi

Comment: Thx, buddy, but still cant work. I have edit my question and added some images. Which version of ShaderDesigner you are using? Mine is 1.5.9.6 @Harish

Comment: Did you make sure your `BaseImage` and `BlendImage` are set to values `0` and `1` in the Uniform Variables Tab and that they are both ticked in the box? I am using the same version of ShaderDesigner.

Comment: what the..., that's the problem, must set texture uniform variables value to integer 0 and 1 and so on.... really thx!!! @Harish